# Can't get canvas element height to equal container height

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to set a series of canvas elements to the same height as their containers:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var c = $('.canvas canvas');
  var container = $(c).parent();

  $(window).resize(respondCanvas);

  function respondCanvas() {
    c.each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr('width', $(container[index]).width());
      $(this).attr('height', $(container[index]).height());
    });
  }

  respondCanvas();
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
#viewport {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.canvas {
  display: flex; /* new addition from answer */
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
#half-breadth,
#profile {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
#body-plan,
#current-section,
#rendering {
  flex: 1 0 32%;
}
canvas {
  flex: auto; /* new addition from answer */
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="viewport" class="flex">
  <div id="half-breadth" class="canvas">
    <canvas id="half-breadth-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="profile" class="canvas">
    <canvas id="profile-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="body-plan" class="canvas">
    <canvas id="body-plan-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="current-section" class="canvas">
    <canvas id="current-section-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="rendering" class="canvas">
    <canvas id="rendering-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</figure>
```

In Google Chrome on OS X at least, the canvas is less than the height of the containing div elements, and in the last 3, the amount it is less is different for each. Without the flex layout, all are a consistent amount smaller than the container. Is there some way to make them all actually exactly the same size? Ideally also a fix also when using flex?

At this point, I don't care about browser compatibility/portability (I'm using flex, so I've already decided to live on the bleeding edge), but I do need to use canvas attributes as far as I'm aware since I do not want to distort the contents (i.e. I can't use CSS 100% width/height).

UPDATE: added CSS to code snippet to reflect accepted solution provided in answers (see comments in CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas elements are not direct children of viewport, so you have to add `display:flex` to the .canvas class and instruct canvas to be `flex:auto`.

Comment: My understanding is that is exactly what jQuery is returning with the height() function (however the getComputedStyle is supposedly more performant). In any case, converting to that suggestion yields exactly the same results. Oddly, I've also noticed that the height grows as the window is resized. I think it's something to do with the div expanding to accommodate the contents.

Comment: Since the canvas elements are not a direct child of viewport, you might have to add `display:flex` to the .canvas class.

Comment: Perfect! The combination of adding `display: flex` to `.canvas` and `flex: auto` to `canvas` took care of everything. I think the `getComputedStyle`/jQuery `height()` didn't affect it at all. If you want to update your answer to reflect the comments, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, my `getComputedStyle` was off-target. I've changed my answer to be on-point. Good luck with your project!

Comment: The getComputedStyle did point me to better code though. Once I started to convert to that, I noticed I was running an `each` loop twice, when I could do both operations in one loop.